# How to combine multiple rows into one row when using SQL statement

Tags: sql, return

How can I combine multiple rows into one row?

Example:

```
1 infill  20
2 test2   30
3 test3   40
```

I want to combine one row like this:

`infill 20, test2 30, test4 40`.

Comment: this will be heavily dependent on which DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a JOIN ; assuming your table is called T, you can do SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* from T as T1, T as T2, T as T3); but chances are this is NOT what you want

Comment: Thanks  a lot for reply, I still confuse.

Comment: 1 infill  20
2 test2   30
3 test3   40    I want one  row infill 20,test 30,test3 40 in one column, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the windows functions called **lead**

```
use TSQL2012

if object_id('pract1') is not null
drop table pract1
go

create table pract1 (
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
name varchar(20) ,
number int 
)

insert into pract1(name,number)
values 
('infill',20),
('test2',30),
('test4',40)


Select concat(name,' ',number) as currentrow, 
concat( lead(name,1) over (order by id), ' ', lead(number,1) over (order by id)) as currentplusonerow,
concat( lead(name,2) over (order by id), ' ', lead(number,2) over (order by id)) as [current+2]
from pract1

currentrow  currentplusonerow   current+2
infill 20   test2 30            test4 40
test2 30    test4 40     
test4 40
```

Edit: I have just noticed that You gave additional comment that You wanted to have everything within one column. Then, the following code will do it for You:

```
Select concat(name,' ',number) +', '+ 
concat( lead(name,1) over (order by id), ' ', lead(number,1) over (order by id)) +', '+
concat( lead(name,2) over (order by id), ' ', lead(number,2) over (order by id)) as [desiredResult]
from pract1
```

There are some empty spaces because ,There is no row current+2 for 2nd and 3rd rows.

Comment: How do you know the OP is using SQL Server?

Comment: I did not really know that but as MINH did not specify that explicitly  I  provided the syntax for sql server as that's the one I feel the most comfortably with. Regards ;-)